# UAPush shared is not identifying in UrbanAirship in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification, xcode8, urbanairship.com

I am working in the PushNotification using UrbanAirship. In that I am getting notifications but for me page number is not displaying. I tried the following code

```
 [[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    UALOG(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);
    // Updates the device token and registers the token with UA
    [[UAPush shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];

}
```

**But for me  in ‘[UAPush shared]’ ‘shared’ is getting error like  “ No known class method for selector 'shared' “**

I have imported the class

```
#import "UAirship.h"
#import "UAPush.h"
```

too even though I am getting lot of errors.

Can anyone help me what was the mistake I did in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are coming from an older version of the SDK. UAPush instance is accessible from `[UAirship push]` however a lot has. Please take a look at the [setup guide](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios/), specifically the [Automatic Integration](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios/#platform-ios-advanced) section. We also provide [migration guides](https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/tree/master/Documentation/Migration) from older SDK versions.